# How do I mock Python properties at an instance level?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

As the [unittest.mock documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) points out:

> Because of the way mock attributes are stored you can’t directly attach a PropertyMock to a mock object. Instead you can attach it to the mock type object

However, I'm encountering cases where I want to mock out multiple values of a property on multiple class instances within a single test.

For example, say I have a `TimeSlot` class with an `availability` property:

```py
class TimeSlot:
    @property
    def availability(self):
        # Run a complex DB query to determine availability
```

... and I have a helper class that sorts a list of `TimeSlot` instances by `availability`:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

from app.helpers import sort_slots
from app.models import TimeSlot


def test_sort_slots_reorders_by_descending_availability():
    slot_a = TimeSlot()
    slot_a.availability = Mock(return_value=0.1) # BOOM!

    slot_b = TimeSlot()
    slot_b.availability = Mock(return_value=0.2)

    slots = [slot_a, slot_b]

    assert sort_slots(slots) == [slot_b, slot_a]
```

Running this test raises an error when I try to assign a Mock (or PropertyMock) to the `availability` property:

`AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Is there any way to mock property return values *per instance* of a Python class?

If not, is there a different way I should be approaching writing unit tests like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `availability` property is defined on the `TimeSlot` class, not instances, so you need to replace it with something at the class level. In this example, I replace it with a class attribute that I then override with instance attributes.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class TimeSlot:
    @property
    def availability(self):
        return 0.0

slot1 = TimeSlot()
slot2 = TimeSlot()
with patch('__main__.TimeSlot.availability', 0.0):
    slot1.availability = 0.1
    slot2.availability = 0.2

    assert slot1.availability == 0.1
    assert slot2.availability == 0.2
```

When the `with` block ends, the original `availability` property will be put back in place.

Comment: note: patch('__main__.TimeSlot.availability', 0.0) was not working for me. I had to go for the full module path instead of __main__

Comment: In this example, @Skratt, `__main__` is the full module path. You're right, though, if I were patching the `myapp.timeslot.TimeSlot` class, then I would need to patch `myapp.timeslot.TimeSlot.availability`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be mocking the TimeSlot object itself. This allows to change how the `availability` property behaves.